# Find all months, days and hours which match for different years and take the mean of them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which has a datetimeindex ranging from `2004-01-01 01:00` to `2014-12-31- 00:00`

```
2004-01-01 00:00:00+01:00          
2004-01-01 01:00:00+01:00          
2004-01-01 02:00:00+01:00         
2004-01-01 03:00:00+01:00
.
.
.
2014-12-30 22:00:00+01:00      
2014-12-30 23:00:00+01:00       
2014-12-31 00:00:00+01:00
```

Id like to find all days and months and hours that are equal independent of year and take the mean of those values.

E.g. If I ask for `"YYYY-01-01 01:00"` I'd be taking the mean of those values stored in the indexes

```
"2004-01-01 01:00", "2005-01-01 01:00", "2006-01-01 01:00", "2007-01-01 01:00", "2008-01-01 01:00", "2009-01-01 01:00", "2010-01-01 01:00", "2011-01-01 01:00", 
"2012-01-01 01:00", "2013-01-01 01:00", "2014-01-01 01:00"
```

I tried creating a new year with hourly frequency and loop over all dates but those take forever. df_inflow is the DataFrame with the index from 2004 to 2014 which is given by the function inflow()

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01'), 
end=pd.to_datetime('2019-12-31'), tz='Europe/Oslo', freq='H')
df_inflow = inflow() 

for date in date_range:
    temp_inflow = df_inflow.loc[(df_inflow.index.strftime('%m-%d %H') == 
    date)].mean()[0]
    # Save mean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `mean`:

```
df = df_inflow.groupby(df_inflow.index.strftime('%m-%d %H')).mean()
```

Or if need `mean` of column `0`:

```
df = df_inflow.groupby(df_inflow.index.strftime('%m-%d %H'))[0].mean()
```

Comment: df = df_inflow.groupby(df_inflow.index.strftime('%m-%d %H'))[0].mean() returned 'Column not found: 0' so I tried to change 0 to the real column name, which returned 'No numeric types to aggregate'

Comment: @Olba12 - so column should be numeric? then use `df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], error='coerce')` -  check also another solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: Got a result now, seem promising. Need to some sanity checks